# Facing problem during upgrading the app after changing the database from SQLite to SQLCipher

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, sqlcipher, android-database, sqlcipher-android

We have a Mobile app where it was using *SQLite* before , but due to security purpose we changed it to *SQLCipher* to provide the encryption , But when i try to install app for the first time it works properly , problem is that when i try to upgrade the app.  App is crashing with below *stacktrace*

```
Caused by: net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: file is not a database: , while compiling: select count(*) from sqlite_master;
        at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method) .....
```

Comment: Did you already check https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/upgrading-to-sqlcipher-4/3283

Answer (score 2):

> The recent release of `SQLCipher 4` introduces many new performance
>   and security enhancements for applications that use `SQLCipher` for
>   secure local data storage. However, the introduction of new default
>   algorithms, increased KDF iterations and a larger page size means that
>   `SQLCipher 4` will not open older databases by default.
>
> This document provides guidance on the upgrade options available to
>   applications that have previously integrated `SQLCipher` versions 1
>   through 3.
>
> ### Option 1: Database File Migration
>
> `SQLCipher` provides a very convenient way to perform an “in place”
>   migration of a `SQLCipher` database using `PRAGMA cipher_migrate.`
>   This does all the work of updating the database file format with a
>   single SQL statement. After migration the database will use all of the
>   latest default settings so an application can immediately benefit from
>   improved performance and security.
>
> `PRAGMA cipher_migrate` be run a single time immediately after the key
>   is provided (i.e. via `sqlite3_key()` or `PRAGMA key` in order to
>   upgrade the database. This would normally occur on the first run after
>   the application is upgraded to perform a one-time conversation.
>
> After the migration is complete the application will no longer need to
>   call the command again on subsequent opens.
>
> ```
> PRAGMA key = '<key material>';
> PRAGMA cipher_migrate;
> ```
>
> The `PRAGMA` will return a single row with the value 0 after
>   successful completion of the migration process. A non-zero column
>   value will be returned in the event of a migration failure. On success
>   the migrated database will remain open and use the same filename.
>
> **Important:** The cipher_migrate `PRAGMA` is potentially expensive because it needs to attempt to open the database for each version to
>   determine the appropriate settings. Therefore an application should
>   NOT call the `PRAGMA` every time a database is opened. Instead, an
>   application should use the recommended process in the cipher_migrate
>   API documentation.
>
> **Note:** `SQLCipher` for Android Java users: when opening a database connection to run PRAGMA cipher_migrate, you must include the
>   `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE` flag as the migration process will temporarily
>   attach a new database during the migration process.
>
> ### Option 2: Backwards Compatibility
>
> The second option is to use the new `SQLCipher 4` library, but use all
>   of the `SQLCipher 3` (or earlier) settings. This requires an
>   application to execute PRAGMA statements immediately after keying the
>   database that will match the settings originally used to create the
>   database.
>
> Starting with `SQLCipher 4.0.1`, you can use the new
>   cipher_compatibility feature. Passing values 1, 2, or 3 to the
>   `PRAGMA` will cause `SQLCipher` to operate with default settings
>   consistent with the respective major version number for the current
>   connection. For example, the following will cause `SQLCipher` to treat
>   the current database as a `SQLCipher 3.x` database:
>
> ```
> PRAGMA cipher_compatibility = 3;
> ```
>
> It is also possible to use the similar cipher_default compatibility
>   `PRAGMA` to set the value for the lifetime of a process before key
>   operations are invoked.

You can find detail [here](https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/upgrading-to-sqlcipher-4/3283).

Comment: where does the pragma belong?  I tried executing it first thing and my database fails to work ("not a database"), but if i use cipher_default_compatibility it works in the same identical place